# Set container max width to XXL breakpoint Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am trying out Bootstrap 5, on my site I do not want the container to grow beyond 1200px which is the XL breakpoint.  Is there a way to either remove the XXL breakpoint or simply tell it not to grow beyond the XL breakpoint.

Preferably within my own custom CSS sheet rather than using SaSS/Less.

Comment: Are you saying you're only concerned with the max-width of container? Why not just set .container { max-width: 1200px }? I don't understand why you'd want to remove the XXL breakpoint completely.

Comment: Yes, well not necessarily remove the breakpoint, just override.  Yes, that appears to achieve what I was looking for quite simply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set max-width on the `.container`...

```
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/R0Y9RwNzqP

Comment: I think you would actually want max-width: 1140px;

Comment: This only works if .container is used for all containers. The other answer is preferred, but if you aren't using the SASS source, this should be something like: .container, .container-fluid, .container-xs, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl, .container-xxl { max-width: 1200px; }

Answer (score 11):

Here's the sass answer for completeness sake: To remove the breakpoint from compiling in sass (including all utilities like `col-xxl-*`) override the default variables `$grid-breakpoints` and `$container-max-widths` and remove `xxl` from the array like so:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
);
```

Make sure to include this before including bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. Knowing how to correctly modify the source files and recompile bootstrap.css is helpful.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the right answer because the question was how to make sure the container-max-width is not getting bigger than XL breakpoint (I read it like "even if the screen is bigger"). Setting .container directly sets the max-width for all (smaller) breakpoints to the same value. No big difference in the outcome but slightly more correct :) The accepted answer makes the container fluid until the screen width reaches XL breakpoint.